# Lose user and page data after reload

Tags: reload, spartacus-storefront

Using Spartacus Storefront 3.1.
On every custom page we did in our project, whenever we reload the browser with F5, we lose the page data and user (this doesn't happen on standard spartacus pages)
Maybe I'm missing something, could it be a guard?

This is how I inject the pages.

```
const staticRoutes: Routes = [{  
path: 'support-tickets',
component: ClaimsTableComponent,
canActivate: [CmsPageGuard, AuthGuard]
}];
```

All I get is this Message when I reload[image]

I forgot to mention, you must be logged to navigate on the site.

Comment: Hi. CMS pages don't need custom routes. Can you add more information to your question? For example, Is this a spartacus upgrade and from which version? Is your ClaimsTableComponent a CMS page? Where are you adding the routes?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the data problem moving all Api requets to AfterViewChecked() instead of OnInit().
Spartacus recovers user and data after refresh but not fast enough to make que request on the OnInit lifecycle.
Since the navigation is forbiden for guests, I still can't get rid of the "not authorized" global message.